# aws workspace client: Archlinux: Not able to copy paste in and out of it. Where as in ubuntu I am able to copy paste in and out

Tags: arch-linux, aws, workspaces

I have installed same version of aws workspace on an archlinux with gnome and also on a pc with ubuntu

In the unbuntu pc I am able to copy paste text in and out of the aws workspace

where as in the archlinux I am not able to copy paste the text in and out of workspace

Where is the issue...

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need provide more information, like if you are using Wayland or X.org. But you can try installing xclip and xsel.

```bash
pacman -S xclip xsel
```

You just had a clipboard redirection problem.

Comment: thanks a lot. I will check this

Comment: I am using X11, `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` shows X11

Comment: I have xclip and xsel installed alredy